# Can a MQL5 EA draw an (uninterrupted) stop loss line?

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

Can a MQL5 EA draw an (uninterrupted) stop loss line, like an indicator could?

If yes: how?

If no: what‘s next best solution?

And will they also show in the strategy tester ( backtesting ) visualization?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, it can

As of 2018-03, any MQL4/5 EA can draw exactly the same range of visualisation effects on MT4/5's GUI Graphs as the Custom Indicator can, so only one's imagination is the limit.

Strategy Tester will do the same ( in case it has been invoked in a **`visual mode [x]`** set on ).

---

## If yes, how?

Principally using:

```
ObjectCreate( anObjectNAME,
              { OBJ_TREND, OBJ_CHANNEL, OBJ_ARROW, OBJ_HLINE, OBJ_VLINE, ... },
              ...
              );
ObjectSet(    anObjectNAME,
              { OBJPROP_ANGLE, OBJPROP_COLOR, OBJPROP_PRICE1, ... },
              ...
              );
```

and related GUI tools, present in the MQL4/5 language.

Several "point-and-move" trading automation frameworks have been built this way and are known to support a fully graphically-based human-trader:trading-engine automation, using but mouse on GUI.

Another option is to integrate the MT4/5 Terminal platform, using as an example an external signalling/messaging plane, like ZeroMQ or nanomsg, with another GUI / MMI / smart-analytics proxies and an external GUI-front-end(s), where indeed no limits apply on one's imagination and fulfillment of visually / analytically augmented-trading needs.

Using this technology, I can confirm ~ < 80 ms RTT latencies to be reasonably achievable ( which is 2+ orders of magnitude faster, than a human-trader's perception and reactive latencies are )

Comment: Thank you, that´s good to hear! It‘s not yet 2018-03, though, so do we have to wait for the next build for it to work?

Comment: :o)                    Time travel?

Comment: Haha, can you quickly pass me the lottery‘s numbers of March through the worm hole? :-)

Comment: Ok, take a pencil and a piece of paper: .............................. 42

Comment: Hi, I finally had time and wanted to implement your suggestions, but I couldn't find an appropriate obejct (the closest to an uninterrupted line would be trendline, not sure if that would work) and ObjectSet seems to be MQL4, not 5... Is it really possible with MQL5?

Comment: Sure it is... `bool  ObjectSet{Double | Int |String}(...)` >>> https://www.mql5.com/files/pdf/mql5.pdf

Comment: I finally did it with OBJ_TREND as you suggested! On the MQL forum itself they said it can‘t be done :-D